# Finding View for Swagger UI web page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I have created a new WEB API project integrating Swashbuckle and Swagger UI.

I am able to access Swagger web page via http://localhost:port/swagger/ui/index#/

However, where is the view/index.html/index.cshtml  for this page?
I am a newbie to MVC, please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `swagger-ui` is served by the `swashbuckle` assembly. The source is not available in your project. You can, however, retrieve the source from [github](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/blob/v5.2.1/Swashbuckle.Core/SwaggerUi/CustomAssets/index.html) and inject it in `swashbuckle` as described in the [swashbuckle documentation](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle#provide-your-own-index-file)

Comment: Thank you for the response. Would you know how can I load both the default black banner provided by ASP.NET web API for navigation, and merge with the page provided in http://localhost:port/swagger/ui/index#/.