# Can swagger UI (or something else) expose web pages?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I know that swagger UI can expose web Apis and I'm using it well now.
But can it deal with web pages? I tried in an .net6 project and it showed nothing.

The objectives are pretty much the same:

1. Show a list of controllers / pages, so the testers can test them.
2. Check if there are any hidden / forgotten / test pages that should be removed.
3. Better if with rich information (get/post, parameters...) as it does for web Apis.

I think they are rational.

I searched for it and there seems no such alternatives (neither java nor .net).

Thanks for your reply.

And, as what [Finding View for Swagger UI web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36337849/finding-view-for-swagger-ui-web-page) said, the source of swagger UI for .net is available. So it can be done by modifying code. But just don't know why others has no such requirements?

Answer (score 0):

Swagger UI is a UI to show and test [OpenAPI](https://www.openapis.org/) specifications, it is not intended to work directly on HTML pages.

If you can get your project to produce such a spec (usually a JSON file) from your application, you can use it with Swagger UI - but still only to work with an API and its data types, not as a complete web application checking/testing utility.

Comment: Swagger-UI is rendering OpenAPI definitions. I don't recommend using it for other purposes. However, if the HTML pages follow the REST principles of APIs, OpenAPI would be an option, HTML pages being a resource with HTML content type.